# Generating decision tree on CUDA

Tags: c++, memory, cuda, binary-tree

I want to generate some decision tree on CUDA, below we have pseudo-code (the code is very primitive, it's only for understand what I wrote):

```
class Node
{
public :
    Node* father;
    Node** sons;
    int countSons;

    __device__ __host__ Node(Node* father)
    {
        this->father = father;
        sons = NULL;
    }
};

__global__ void GenerateSons(Node** fathers, int countFathers*, Node** sons, int* countSons)
{
    int Thread_Index = (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x) + threadIdx.x;

    if(Thread_Index < *(countFathers))
    {
        Node* Thread_Father = fathers[Thread_Index];
        Node** Thread_Sons;
        int Thread_countSons;
        //Now we are creating new sons for our Thread_Father
        /*
        * Generating Thread_Sons for Thread_Father;
        */
        Thread_Father->sons = Thread_Sons; 
        Thread_Father->countSons = Thread_countSons;

        //Wait for others
            /*I added here __syncthreads because I want to count all generated sons
             by threads
            */
            *(countSons) += Thread_countSons;
        __syncthreads();

        //Get all generated sons from whole Block and copy to sons

        if(threadIdx.x == 0)
        {
            sons = new Node*[*(countSons)];
        }
        /*I added here __syncthreads because I want to allocated array for sons
            */
        __syncthreads();

        int Thread_Offset;
        /*
        * Get correct offset for actual thread
        */
        for(int i = 0; i < Thread_countSons; i++)
            sons[Thread_Offset + i] = Thread_Sons[i];
    }
}

void main ()
{
    Node* root = new Node();
    //transfer root to kernel by cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy
    Node* root_d = root->transfer();

    Node** fathers_d;
    /*
    * preapre array with father root and copy him to kernel
    */

    int* countFathers, countSons;
    /*
    * preapre pointer of int for kernel and for countFathers set value 1
    */

    for(int i = 0; i < LevelTree; i++)
    {
        Node** sons = NULL;
        int threadsPerBlock = 256; 
        int blocksPerGrid = (*(countFathers)/*get count of fathers*/  + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;
        GenerateSons<<<blocksPerGrid , threadsPerBlock >>>(fathers_d, countFathers, sons, countSons);
        //Wait for end of kernel call
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        //replace
        fathers_d = sons;
        countFathers = countSons;
    }
}
```

So, it works for 5-level (generating decision tree for checkers), but on the 6-level I have error. In some place in the code of kernel the malloc is returning `NULL` , and for me it's a information that some of thread in blockThreads cannot alloc more memory. I'm pretty sure that I'm cleaning all the object that I don't need, on each end of call kernel. I thinking, that I'm cannot understand some facts of usage memory in CUDA. If I'm creating object in local memory of thread and the Kernel ends his activity, then on the secound start of kernel I can see that nodes from the first call of kernel are. So my question is where the objects `Node` from first call-of-kernel are stored? Are they stored in the local memory of thread in block ? So if it's true then on each call of my kernel function I will reduced the space of local memory of this thread?

I'm using GT 555m with Compute capability 2.1, CUDA SDK 5.0, Visual Studio 2010 Premium with NSight 3.0

Comment: You're calling new in the kernel and never calling delete. Since you're using ____global____ void GenerateSons I'm willing to bet that you're running out of memory on the device.

Comment: Ok my device has 2Gb of space, and sizeof(Node) = 28. First call genrate 7 sons, secound 49, next 379 and last correct call 2769. So my device generated 3204 sons which gives 87Kb ???

Comment: hmmm, i wonder if new is pulling memory from shared memory. I'll have to look up the documentation.

Comment: I think the "register of thread" == "local memory of thread" is filled out, but I'm not sure. At the moment, the only solution that I have in my head is to copying new sons to global memory from kernel...

Comment: what are the values of `someValue` and `someValue2`. And what are you hoping to achieve by calling `__syncthreads()` twice in that kernel?

Comment: edited code with description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey,

I found that, `new` and `malloc`invoke in kernel are allocated in **global memory** on device.
Also I found this

> By default, CUDA creates a heap of 8MB.

[CUDA Application Design and Development, page 128](http://books.google.pl/books?id=Y-XmJO2uwvMC&pg=PA128&lpg=PA128&dq=cudaLimitMallocHeapSize%20defalut&source=bl&ots=WiOsS2x7IU&sig=FfGUzVYY5trLB8OPZRzYvzYC8jk&hl=pl&sa=X&ei=ykcqUZqoJoHTswbZ84GwAw&ved=0CHwQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=cudaLimitMallocHeapSize%20defalut&f=false)

So, I used this method `cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitMallocHeapSize, 128*1024*1024);` to increase heap memory on device to 128Mb and the program generated correctly the 6 level of tree (22110 sons), but in fact I get some memory leaks... which I need to find.